# How to loop over two iterables at once, insert into mysql by python like this?

Tags: python, mysql, json

Here is json code

```
    item = {'link': [u'http://www.google.com/google/1.html',
      u'http://www.google.com/google/2.html',
      u'http://www.google.com/google/3.html',],
 'title': [u'title1',
       u'title2',
       u'title3',
       ]}
```

I want to insert these data into mysql,like

```
id,link,title #one by one.
1,http://www.google.com/google/1.html,title1
2,http://www.google.com/google/2.html,title2
3,http://www.google.com/google/3.html,title3
```

my python code

```
titles = item['title']
links = item['link']
for title in titles:
    for link in links:
        #excute sql
        xxx.excute(sql % (link, title))
```

but it doesn't work,it insert like this

```
1,http://www.google.com/google/1.html,title1
2,http://www.google.com/google/2.html,title1
3,http://www.google.com/google/3.html,title1
```

So,Is there any other way?

Comment: Just for future reference, a better way to say this is that you want to loop over two iterables at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the lists together:

```
to_insert = zip(item['link'], item['title'])
for link, title in to_insert:
    xxx.excute(sql % (link, title))
```